# Acumatica Mobile - Is it possible to make a Container with a value of a field displayed together with the container name?

Tags: acumatica

I'm new to Acumatica and I was wondering if this is possible to make in Acumatica Mobile App.

[image: Customers Screen]
[image: Customer Details]

I have created 3 custom fields in the Customer screen where it can calculate the total amount of AR Invoices, Hold Checks, and Voided Payments of the customer.
I want it to be displayed in mobile app just like the images I have attached.

The first image I have attached shows where the Customers list and it should display the Name of the Customer together with the `TotalARBalance` field. The second image shows if you select a specific Customer it will display its total amount of `TotalARBalance`, `TotalHoldBalance`, and `TotalVoidedBalance`  with its  Container Name accordingly.

This is the Customers screen in Web App:
[image: Customer Screen]

This is my code for the Customers screen:

```
add screen AR303000 {
  add container "CustomerSummary" {
    add field "CustomerID"
    add field "Status" {
      forceIsDisabled = True
      }
    }
    
  add container "ARInvoice" {
    add field "RefNbr"
    add field "Status"
    add field "Balance"
    add field "DueDate"
    }
    
  add container "HoldChecks" {
    add field "PaymentRefNbr"
    add field "DateOfHold"
    add field "PaymentAmount"
    add field "ExtensionDate"
    }
  
  add container "VoidedPayments" {
    add field "ReferenceNbr"
    add field "VoidStatus"
    add field "PaymentAmount"
    add field "DateVoided"
    }  
}
```

I tried to look in the Documentation for Mobile Framework Guide but I found nothing similar to what I want to make

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two questions here:

1. Adding the TotalARBalance custom field to the Customer List Screen (AR3030PL).

-Make sure the TotalARBalance custom field is visible in the UI web screen.

-Get the proper name to be used in the MSDL Code (Mobile customization) for this field. In order to do this you must check the WSDL Schema for that screen (AR3030PL).

-Then make sure that you set the proper value to the fieldsToShow property for your Result container, see below:

```
add screen AR3030PL {
  add container "Result" {
    fieldsToShow = 5
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "Field1"
    add field "Field2"
    add field "Field3"
    add field "Field4"
    add field "TotalARBalance"
    add containerAction "editDetail" {
      behavior = Open
      redirect = True
     }
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
      redirect = True
    }
  }
 }
```

2. About the container with custom field's values.
   Out of the box I don't think the Mobile app could render the exact same design.
   You could create a group with the same names as you showed in your image but the field's value won't be displayed when the group is collapse. However, if the user uncolpases the group then they will be able to see the custom field's value for that group.

See below quick snippet for the AR Invoice group in your image:

```
................
add group "ARInvoiceGroup" {
    displayName = "AR Invoice"
    collapsable = True
    collapsed = True
    add field "TotalARBalance"
  }
 #add other two groups here
  ........
```

You can review more information about groups on this help article below:
https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=37c0e79c-e89e-4e41-8b05-ca3df5e053f1